# Avconv only converts a single frame when converting a GIF to WebM format

Tags: video, video-conversion, libav

I am trying to convert GIF images into WebM videos with [`avconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html), but I only get a single frame into the WebM video.

Example GIF:

[image]

I use the flowing command:

```
avconv -i horse.gif -c:v libvpx -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1M horse.webm
```

Output from the command:

```
avconv version 0.8.17-6:0.8.17-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 15 2015 17:00:31 with gcc 4.7.2
Input #0, image2, from 'horse.gif':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: gif, pal8, 500x269, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Incompatible pixel format 'pal8' for codec 'libvpx', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x1fd68e0] w:500 h:269 pixfmt:pal8
[avsink @ 0x1fd67c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x1fc19c0] w:500 h:269 fmt:pal8 -> w:500 h:269 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[libvpx @ 0x1fd7440] v1.1.0
Output #0, webm, to 'horse.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: libvpx, yuv420p, 500x269, q=10-42, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif -> libvpx)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=      12kB time=0.04 bitrate=2517.2kbits/s
video:12kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.930636%
```

The original gif image is 901KB big and the resulting WebM video only 13 KB.

Comment: Using the real ffmpeg worked. You can put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have any deep experience with [`avconv`](https://libav.org/avconv.html) but from [what I am reading in this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664093/117259), `avconv` seems to be buggy when it comes to handling animated GIFs. The solution suggested is to just use [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org) instead.